# Vuejs fails to load svg image?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

In one of my component, I'm trying to load an svg image but vuejs/webpack fails.

Here's my code :

```
<template>
    <img src="../../assets/public/images/sad.svg" />
</template>

<script>
export default {}
</script>
```

And the error :

> ERROR in ./src/assets/public/images/sad.svg
>   Module parse failed:
>   /home/cabox/workspace/src/assets/public/images/sad.svg Line 1:
>   Unexpected token <                                  You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | 
>   | 
>   | 
>   @
>   ./~/vue-html-loader!./~/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=template&index=0!./src/components/tooltip.vue
>   1:205-258 1:592-645

From what I understand, Vuejs (or Webpack) tries to interpret the content of .svg. And this is not what I want.

Here's my webpack config for svg :

```
{ test: "\.svg", loader: "file-loader?mimetype=image/svg+xml" },
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you open the file in the browser? I'd say it's a Webpack problem rather than VueJS.

Comment: Yes, the file can be loaded. And it's also it's correct path since the error message contain the beginning of the file.

Comment: You could try using `svg-loader` instead of `file-loader`.

Comment: I tried svg-loader with hopes. The compilation works, but then when loading the page, I have this new error : `Unexpected token <
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.`

Comment: In my opinion, svg-loader works for webpack, but when vuejs tries to compile src="...", it doesn't take into consideration the svg-loader rule and then fails. But my knowledge only go up to here.

Comment: See what happens if you remove that self closing tag (so it's just `<img src="...">`) I have seen people have issues with vuejs and self-closing tags.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one works for me:

```
{test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
```

Its a regular expression to process any file with an svg extension as a static resource the way you are looking for.

I use it with other font loaders for bootstrap or other glyphfonts:

```
{test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'},
{test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream'},
{test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
{test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml'}
```

Using that regular expression you can probably change the loader to file and inline it like you were using.

Comment: Awesome that worked for me. Now I have to understand why it places my files in dist/dist/ instead of dist/ ...